# Compare variable value with another variable value greater than 99 in EL / JSTL

Tags: jsp, jstl, el

The following EL snippet compares variable with another variable:

```
<c:set var="age" value="100"/>
<c:set var="ageLimit" value="18"/>

<c:if test="${age >= ageLimit}">
 <c:out value="You are eligible for voting! Your age is ${age} and ageLimit is ${ageLimit}"/>
</c:if>

<c:if test="${age < ageLimit}">
 <c:out value="You are NOT eligible for voting! Your age is ${age} and ageLimit is ${ageLimit}"/>
</c:if>
```

When the age value goes beyond 99, EL fails to return the correct result and instead prints the following wring result.

```
You are NOT eligible for voting! age is 100 and ageLimit is 18
```

How to get EL to print the correct value?